# Does Dreamweaver subversion support branching?

Tags: dreamweaver, svn

Adobe Dreamweaver added support for subversion in CS4.

I have CS5, I am able to update and commit, they even have a very easy rollback option where you can promote any revision number to "head" but I cannot figure out anyway to branch using it.

According to Adobe their subversion support is not full featured. But I cannot find any resource that stats what all is supported.

So is branching one of the things not supported? 
(I kind of feel like whats the point without branching?) If you *can* do it, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read [these articles](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/using_subversion_pt1.html)?  They describe how to use Dreamweaver's Subversion support, in detail.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't support branching. You need to handle branching externally to DW.

If you want to edit a branch in DW then you need to change the path in your repo server setup to point to the branch (instead of the trunk) you want to edit.